# Scala: How to get back the key itself when a Map does not contain it

Tags: scala

Let's assume the following `Map`:

```
val map = Map("eins" -> "one", "zwei" -> "two", "drei" -> "three")
```

As expected `map` returns the value associated with a given key:

```
scala> map("eins")
res0: String = one
scala> map("zwei")
res1: String = two
...
```

and of course it crashes if a given key does not exist:

```
scala> map("zehn")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: zehn
```

Is there a way to get back the key itself instead of an exception?

```
map("zehn") -> "zehn"
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can do `map.getOrElse("zehn", "zehn")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val map = Map("eins" -> "one", "zwei" -> "two", "drei" -> "three").withDefault(identity)
```

Comment: Wow... this is exactly the elegant solution I was looking for ;-)